# How to rename a rule in Business Central without retyping the existing name?

Tags: drools, jbpm, kie-workbench

I would like to slightly rename a rule by adding some prefix, suffix, etc.

[image: Rename button]

When I click on the rename button it gives me an empty text box, which means I have to retype the whole name.

[image: Empty rename TextField]

In order not to retype the whole name I first try to copy the existing name in the rule title with the mouse pointer, but that it just not possible.

[image: Selecting the rule name]

My questions:

- How to rename a rule in Business Central without retyping the
  existing name?
- Or at least how to copy-paste an existing rule name
  into the empty rename text field?

Using Business Central version 7.29.0.Final.

Answer (score 1):

> How to rename a rule in Business Central without retyping the existing name? 
>   Or at least how to copy-paste an existing rule name into the empty rename text field

There is no way you can add prefix, suffix to existing rule name through business-central console. But you can clone repository into filesystem using `git clone` command, rename rule in filesystem and `push` the changes back to business-central git repository.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I cannot tell our clients who are not programmers to use git.

Answer (score 0):

> Or at least how to copy-paste an existing rule name into the empty rename text field?

One workaround to copy-paste rule name is to click on "Overview" tag for the assest and click on "Metadata" tab.

Here you can find the rule name under the "Note" attribute, you can copy rule name from there and paste it while renaming it.